# Method to eliminate cross site scripts

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-site

My application has lot of cross site scripting vulnerablities. I need a common C# function so that will avoid\eliminate all the cross site scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Server.HtmlEncode()* will render them harmless.